# Простой ООП калькулятор с наследованием

Tags: php

Я сделал второй класс, который наследует всё у первого.
Он должен вывести результат метода **sum()** в квадрате, но этого не происходит, потому что изначально
у свойства **result** значение **0**, мне надо этому свойство присвоить значение **$firstNumber** но я не знаю, как?

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset:utf-8');
error_reporting(-1);

class CalkSum{
    public function __construct($firstNumber){
        $this->firstNumber = $firstNumber;
    }
    public $result = 0;

    public function sum(){
        for($i = 0; $i < func_num_args(); $i++){
            $this->result = $this->result+ func_get_args()[$i];
        }
        return $this->result + $this->firstNumber;
    }
}

class SumSquare extends CalkSum{
    public function square(){
        return $this->result * $this->result;
    }
}

$ob2 = new SumSquare(100);

$res1 = $ob2->sum(1,2,3);

echo 'Результат сложения ' . $ob2->firstNumber . ' + аргументы = ' . $res1;
echo '<br>';
echo $res1 . ' в квадрате = ' . $ob2->square();
```

106* 106 должно вывести 11236, а у меня выводит 36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CalkSum{
 public $result = 0;
public function __construct($firstNumber){
    $this->firstNumber = $firstNumber;
    $this->result = $firstNumber;
}

public function sum(){
    for($i = 0; $i < func_num_args(); $i++){
        $this->result = $this->result+ func_get_args()[$i];
    }
    return $this->result;
 }
}

class SumSquare extends CalkSum{
  public function square(){
    return $this->result * $this->result;
  }
}

$ob2 = new SumSquare(100);
var_dump($ob2);
$res1 = $ob2->sum(1,2,3);

echo 'Результат сложения ' . $ob2->firstNumber . ' + аргументы = ' . $res1;
echo '<br>';
echo $res1 . ' в квадрате = ' . $ob2->square();
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы результат метода `sum` просто возвращаете, поэтому у вас `$result = 6`, нужно сначала обновить переменную и потом её вернуть, вот так:

```
public function sum(){
    for($i = 0; $i < func_num_args(); $i++){
        $this->result = $this->result+ func_get_args()[$i];
    }
    $this->result += $this->firstNumber
    return $this->result;
}
```

Comment: теперь вообще firstNumber не складывает

Comment: я же его объявил в __construct

Answer (score 0):

Объявите свойство класса. Иначе куда заносить значение?

```
class CalkSum{

   public $firstNumber;

   ...
```

Comment: я же его объявил в __construct

Comment: в конструкторе вы не объявляете а присваиваете значение. объявление свойств (переменных класса) происходит обычно в первых строчках описания класса.

Comment: Вы не поверите, но волшебным образом свойство $firstNumber создастся не смотря на то, что оно не объявлено http://ideone.com/ki0Q0n